# File upload total

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, file, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jquery file upload.

For my application, I'm allowing users to upload 15mb of images per product. I want to have a little span on the page with the file upload that says "You have 10 mb left" if you've already uploaded 5 mb worth of images.

I was going to do this via something like:

`<div>You have <span class='spaceAvailable'>10</span> left</div>`

and then on jqueryFileUpload's add callback when you add another image (say it's 3mb for example), get the value of `$(".spaceAvailable")`, and subtract the new image size from spaceAvailable (so 10-3 = 7). When I hit zero, I would just not call `data.submit()` and alert an error.

But couldn't someone edit the html, making the span.spaceAvailable something like 1000MB and try and upload? What's a better solution to prevent this?

Comment: That any novice programmer can do but the way you calculate must be something which doesn't get effected even though anyone edits your value!!! Everytime you must check through total number size of uploaded files!!

Comment: Save your total uploaded file size in javascript variable and check in the callback of file uploader and check for the **condition** you want show the required alert. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Never leave the validation on javascript only. Add server side validation, which returns false (or something like this) if sum of file sizes is bigger than you want. Then just serve it with .fail (or something you want) function.